Discord.JS TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reduce')
Receiving the following error when using any interaction in Discord.js
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reduce')
    at BaseInteraction (node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\BaseInteraction.js:106:43)
    at MessageComponentInteraction (node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageComponentInteraction.js:17:5)
    at ButtonInteraction (node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\ButtonInteraction.js:9:1)
    at handle (node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:90:25)
    at module.exports (node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
    at handlePacket (node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:355:31)
    at <anonymous> (node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:239:12)
    at emit (node_modules\@vladfrangu\async_event_emitter\dist\index.cjs:282:31)
    at <anonymous> (node_modules\@discordjs\ws\dist\index.js:1190:51)
    at emit (node_modules\@vladfrangu\async_event_emitter\dist\index.cjs:282:31)
    at onMessage (node_modules\@discordjs\ws\dist\index.js:1005:14)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues:95:5)


This is caused by a recent breaking change in the Discord API. The current solution is to downgrade Discord.js to 14.14.1.
Follow this Discord.JS GitHub issue for more information
